# Java: ClassCastException; casting Player class to class that extend Player

Tags: java, object, classcastexception

I am having trouble understanding how to fix this issue of creating a bot that extends the Player class in my online multiplayer game.

If I try to make classes that extend Player (NPC_Type1, NPC_Type2, etc..), I want to be able register with the extended class not the Player since each class will do something different.

Just casting it to the proper type gives me an error:

Cast Example:

```
NPC_Type1 p = (NPC_Type1)registerPlayer(null)
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.testgame.server.model.player.Player cannot be cast to class
> com.testgame.server.model.player.NPC_Type1
> (com.testgame.server.model.player.Player and
> com.testgame.server.model.player.NPC_Type1 are in unnamed module of
> loader 'app')

PlayerManager Code:

```
 private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>(); // keep track of players in game (maybe bots to?)

 public Player registerPlayer(Channel c) { //netty channel
        Player player = new Player(context, c);
        if ((!player.isBot())) // bots are exempt
        {
            //do stuff
            return player;
        }
        players.add(player); // add player to list
 }

 public Player createBot(
        String name,
        int ID,
        int[] startPosition,
        float startDamage
    ) {
        Player p = registerPlayer(null); //cast error here
        p.register(
                name,
                ID,
                startPosition,
                startDamage,
        );
        return p;
    }
// adding bots to a list
 public List<? extends Player> listBots() {
     List<? extends Player> bot = new ArrayList<>();
     for (Player p : bots) {
         if (p.isRegistered() && p.isBot()) {
             bot.add(p); //compile error
         }
     }

     return bot;
 }
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix with maybe a small example?

Comment: You're only creating a `Player` instance, here: `Player player = new Player(context, c);`. That isn't an instance of `NPC_Type1`, so you can't cast to `NPC_Type1`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, I get that, but how would I get it to work for all instances? Player,NPC_Type1, NPC_Type2, etc.. Since the rest extend Player

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there somehow I can pass as a parameter to tell what type of object to create?

Comment: Yes, but we don't really know enough about the situation to know what to suggest.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean, what other information do you need?

Comment: You should think about what information you need to provide to `registerPlayer` for it to work out what type to initialize. But I'm afraid Stack Overflow really isn't designed for this sort of back-and-forth. You know why the cast is failing - I suggest you now go and do research and try various different approaches to creating an instance of the right type.

Comment: From a modelling real world stuff standpoint, having `NPC_TypeFoo` extend `Player` doesn't make a lot of sense and will probably lead to problems. Extending a class creates an "is a" relation, as in "an NPC is a Player." An NPC is clearly not a player since NPC literally means Non-Player Character. I'd recommend creating an abstract `Character` base class and have `Player` and all NPC types extend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object can be cast to it's own class or a class that it extends (any class in the hierarchy down to Object) as well as any interface it implements.
Player is your base class here which are extended by your NPC_TypeX classes.
Therefore, an NPC_TypeX object can be cast to Player but not the other around.

This works:

```
Player p = new NPC_Type1();
```

This does not:

```
NPC_Type1 p = new Player(); // Syntax error
```

Also

```
Player p = new NPC_Type1();
NPC_Type1 n = (NPC_Type1) p; // This is fine since p is of type NPC_Type1

Player p2 = new Player();
NPC_Type1 n2 = (NPC_Type1) p2; // ClassCastException
```

In your registerPlayer method you are instantiating Player objects, not NPC_TypeX objects.

Since you may want to be able to register any Player type you could pass the Player object (or objects of an extending class) into the method if you change the method:

```
 public Player registerPlayer(Channel c, Player player) { //netty channel
        if ((!player.isBot())) // bots are exempt
        {
            //do stuff
            return player;
        }
        players.add(player); // add player to list
 }
```

Using thet method:

```
NPC_Type1 npc = new NPC_Type1();
registerPlayer(null, npc);
```

Comment: I seem to get an error when trying to add player to the list ```players```